# How to set maximum retry attempts for AmqpConnection

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-retry

Is it possible to set retry attempts for rabbitmq connection? If possible how to do that?

I am currently connecting to AMQP (RabbitMQ) from my application, if rabbitmq is down then AmqpConnectionException is thrown and it retries 10 times to establish connection again.

```
15:50:41.533 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-173] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - **Consumer raised exception,** processing can restart if the connection factory supports it.
 **Exception summary**: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
15:50:41.533 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-173] INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
15:50:42.565 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-172] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it.
 **Exception summary**: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
15:50:42.565 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-172] INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
15:50:43.567 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-17] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it.
**Exception summary**: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
15:50:43.567 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-17] INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
15:50:44.581 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-181] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it.
 **Exception summary:** org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
15:50:44.581 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-181] INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
15:50:45.589 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-180] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it.
 **Exception summary**: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
15:50:45.589 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-180] INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
15:50:47.606 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-179] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it.
 **Exception summary**: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
15:50:47.606 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-179] INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
15:50:48.616 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-178] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it.
 **Exception summary**: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
15:50:48.616 [http-nio-8443-exec-4] ERROR u.c.o.s.v.messaging.config.Sender - Excception has happened connecting to RabbitMQ
15:50:48.626 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-178] INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

How to reduce this retry attempts to 3 times and then exit.

Am using CachingConnectionFactory  to get connected to rabbitmq server.

```
public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
                CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
            connectionFactory.setHost(env.getProperty("rabbitmq.host"));
            connectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env
                    .getProperty("rabbitmq.port")));
            connectionFactory.setUsername(env.getProperty("rabbitmq.user"));
            connectionFactory.setPassword(env.getProperty("rabbitmq.pass"));
            return connectionFactory;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The (fixed) recovery interval defaults to 5 seconds; this can be configured.

Starting with version 1.5, you can now configure a `BackOff`, such as an `ExponentialBackOff` to increase the times between reconnection attempts.

The `ExponentialBackOff` can be configured to stop retrying altogether after some time, at which time the container is stopped.

See [what's new in 1.5](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/_introduction.html#_simplemessagelistenercontainer_backoff_support).